# Assignment problem with 2 workers per job

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming, hungarian-algorithm, assignment-problem

**Problem setup**

Currently we are working at dispatching problem for a food-tech startup (e-grocery). We have jobs (orders to be delivered) and workers (couriers/packers/universal) The problem is to to assign orders to workers efficiently. At first step we've decided to optimise CTE (click-to-eat - time between order placement and order delivery)

**The problem itself**

The problem comes from the fact that sometimes it is efficient to have 2 worker per one job and not a single executor, because packer may know store "map" and courier may have bicycle what allows to execute job faster comparing to each of them separately even accounting for order transfer costs.

We have researched algorithms and found that our problem looks like [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) and there is an algorithmic solution ([Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)), but the problem is that classic problem requires "each job is assigned to one worker and each worker is assigned one job" while in our case it is sometimes efficient to have 2 workers per one job.

**What we have tried so far**

1. insert (*packer A* + *universal B*) combination into the matrix of costs, but in this case we cannot add  *universal B* into the matrix, because as a result we can get that *universal B* will be assigned to 2 jobs (as a separate unit and as part of combination with *packer A*)
2. Implement 2 Hungarian algorithms consequently: at first assign packaging, after that assign delivery. It works in vast majority of cases, but sometimes leads to inefficient solutions. If needed, I will add an example.

**The question itself**

I've googled a lot, but could not find anything that could direct me to the solution of the problem. If you have any links or ideas that we can use as a clue to solution, I will be happy to check them.

**EDIT:** I've added the brute force solution of my question. Hope that helps to understand the problem better

```py
# constants
delivery_speed = np.array([5, 13]) # km per hour
delivery_distance = np.array([300, 2700])  # meters
flight_distance = np.array([500, 1900]) # meters время подлета
positions_amount = np.array([4, 8]) # number of positions in one order
assembly_speed = np.array([2, 3]) # minutes per position
transit_time = 5 * 60 # sec to transfer order
number_of_orders = 3 # number of orders in a batch
number_of_workers = 3 

# size of optimization matrix
matrix_size = max(number_of_workers, number_of_orders)


# maximum diagonal length for delivery and flight
max_length = np.sqrt(max(delivery_distance)**2/2)
max_flight_length = np.sqrt(max(flight_distance)**2/2)


# store positions
A = np.array([delivery_distance[1], delivery_distance[1]])
B = np.array([A[0] + max_length / 2, A[1]])

possible_order_position_x = np.array([-max_length/2, max_length]) + A[0]
possible_order_position_y = np.array([-max_length, max_length]) + A[1]
possible_courier_position_x = np.array([-max_flight_length/2, max_flight_length]) + A[0]
possible_courier_position_y = np.array([-max_flight_length, max_flight_length]) + A[1]


# generate random data 
def random_speed(speed_array):
    return np.random.randint(speed_array[0], speed_array[1]+1)

def location(possible_x, possible_y):
    return np.random.randint([possible_x[0], possible_y[0]],
                             [possible_x[1], possible_y[1]],
                             size=2)


def generate_couriers():
    # generate couriers 
    couriers = {}
    for courier in range(number_of_workers):
        couriers[courier] = {
            'position': location(possible_courier_position_x, possible_courier_position_y),
            'delivery_speed': random_speed(delivery_speed),
            'assembly_speed': random_speed(assembly_speed),
        }
    return couriers
    
couriers = generate_couriers()

store_location = {0: A, 1:B}

def generate_orders():
    # generate orders
    orders = {}
    for order in range(number_of_orders):
        orders[order] = {
            'number_of_positions': random_speed(positions_amount),
            'store_position': store_location[np.random.randint(2)],
            'customer_position': location(possible_order_position_x, possible_order_position_y)
        }
    return orders

orders = generate_orders()
orders


# functions to calculate assembly and delivery speed 
def travel_time(location_1, location_2, speed):
    # time to get from current location to store
    flight_distance = np.linalg.norm(location_1 - location_2)
    delivery_speed = 1000 / (60 * 60) * speed # meters per second
    return flight_distance / delivery_speed # seconds


def assembly_time(courier, order):
    flight_time = travel_time(courier['position'], order['store_position'], courier['delivery_speed'])
    assembly_time = courier['assembly_speed'] * order['number_of_positions'] * 60

    
    return int(flight_time + assembly_time)
assembly_time(couriers[0], orders[0])

def brute_force_solution():
    best_cte = np.inf
    best_combination = [[],[]]

    for first_phase in itertools.permutations(range(number_of_workers), number_of_orders):
        assembly_time_s = pd.Series(index = range(number_of_orders), dtype=float)
        for order, courier in enumerate(first_phase):
            assembly_time_s[order] = assembly_time(couriers[courier], orders[order]) 


        # start to work with delivery
        for second_phase in itertools.permutations(range(number_of_workers), number_of_orders):
            delivery_time_s = pd.Series(index = range(number_of_orders), dtype=float)
            for order, courier in enumerate(second_phase):
                delivery_time = travel_time(orders[order]['store_position'],
                                            orders[order]['customer_position'],
                                            couriers[courier]['delivery_speed'])
                # different cases for different deliveries
                if courier == first_phase[order]:
                    # if courier assemblied order, then deliver immidietely 
                    delivery_time_s[order] = delivery_time
                elif courier not in first_phase:
                    # flight during assembly, wait if needed, transfer time, delivery
                    flight_time = travel_time(orders[order]['store_position'],
                                              couriers[courier]['position'],
                                              couriers[courier]['delivery_speed'])
                    wait_time = max(flight_time - assembly_time_s[order], 0)
                    delivery_time_s[order] = transit_time + wait_time + delivery_time
                else: 
                    # case when shopper transfers her order and moves deliver other 
                    # check if second order is in the same store
                    first_phase_order = first_phase.index(courier)
                    if (orders[first_phase_order]['store_position'] == orders[order]['store_position']).all():
                        # transit time - fixed and happens only once! 
                        # wait, if second order has not been assemblied yet
                        # time to assembly assigned order
                        assembly_own = assembly_time_s[first_phase_order]
                        # time to wait, if order to deliver is assemblied slower
                        wait_time = max(assembly_time_s[order] - assembly_own, 0)
                        # delivery time is calculated as loop start
                        delivery_time_s[order] = transit_time + wait_time + delivery_time
                    else:
                        # transit own order - flight to the other store - wait if needed - tansit order - delivery_time
                        flight_time = travel_time(orders[first_phase_order]['store_position'],
                                                  orders[order]['store_position'],
                                                  couriers[courier]['delivery_speed'])
                        arrival_own = (assembly_time_s[first_phase_order] + transit_time + flight_time)
                        wait_time = max(assembly_time_s[order] - arrival_own, 0)
                        delivery_time_s[order] = ((transit_time * 2) + flight_time + wait_time + delivery_time)
            
            delivery_time_s = delivery_time_s.astype(int)

            # calculate and update best result, if needed
            cte = (assembly_time_s + delivery_time_s).sum()
            if cte < best_cte:
                best_cte = cte
                best_combination = [list(first_phase), list(second_phase)]
                
    return best_cte, best_combination


best_cte, best_combination = brute_force_solution()
```

Comment: Why not just split each job into two tasks (packer task and courier task) and run the Hungarian algorithm once?

Comment: @kaya3 can you explain how to run once? We cannot do it, because we can make worker 1 do job 1, worker 2 do job 1, worker 1 + worker 2 do job 1, worker 1 + worker 3 do job 2. therefore we get that some assignments will be impossible to satisfy in combination

Comment: Do you need the optimum solution, or is a heuristic sufficient?

Comment: @RBarryYoung At first we would be happy with heuristic, but once our sales grow, we will want to find optimal solution and do it fast enough for production

Comment: How many workers and how many jobs are you solving for...roughly?  And is it the case that when you assign 2 workers to 1 job that they are both "occupied" for the duration of the job?  This brings up another question of how you are dealing with time in your model...

Comment: @AirSquid at maximum we expect to have 3000 workers and 600 jobs to be assigned. The job is delivery, so if we assign packer and courier to 1 job, packer is occupied during the whole time of job and packer is free after packaging. We input these assumptions to our cost function

Comment: This is no longer an assignment problem. I would start writing this down as a formal optimization problem (and solve as a MIP/CP model). That provides a good tool for experimentation (does it work, evaluate solutions, evaluate performance). If needed one can later develop a heuristic for performance. With the optimization model, you can at least compare with optimal solutions (otherwise you are totally in the dark wrt solution quality). If you have no experience with this, maybe hire a student to help with this.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen i have written a brute force algorithm as baseline and it works for small numbers, but it is not inefficient in production (obviously). Thanks for the suggestion, I will try to formalise my problem in math terms

Comment: @ArtyomAkselrod you mention that you have a brute-force implementation, if it is simple to share I highly recommend sharing it, as it will let people answer your question. Right now it is very vague.

Comment: @ldog I have added the brute force solution to the end of my question

Answer (score 1):

The Hungarian algorithm is an antiquated solution that remains popular for some unexplicable reason I do not understand (perhaps because it is conceptually simple.)

Use Minimum Cost Flow to model your problem. It is far more flexible, and has many efficient algorithms. It can also be proved to solve any problem the Hungarian algorithm can (proof is simple.)

Given the very vague description of your problem, you would want to model the underlying graph G=(V,E) with two layers of nodes V = (O,W), where O are the orders and W are the workers.

Edges can be directed, with each Worker having an edge with capacity 1  to every possible order. Connect the source node to the worker with edge capacity 1 and connect each order node to the sink node with capacity 2 (or higher, allowing for more workers per order).

What I described above is actually a maxflow instance not a MCF as it assigns no weights. You can however, assign weights to any of the edges.

Given your problem formulation, I don't understand how this is even an assignment problem, can you not use a simple first come first assign (queue) type strategy, given you don't seem to have any criteria to have a worker prefer working on a certain order over another.

Comment: sorry, but I obviously have criteria, I need to optimise click-to-eat - so usually closest worker to the job is the most preferable. However, sometimes bicycle rider in a long distance from job could be more efficient than pedestrian courier. At my delivery service we get X orders per minute and we should assign our workers to these orders   what is actually an assignment problem, i believe

Comment: so our costs is flight time (time to get to the shop) + buy required  orders's items + deliver.  Sometimes we have 2 workers assigned to one order, because it may be efficient to buy items by one worker and deliver by another

Comment: Okay, you are being very vague about how your problem is set up. If I understand correctly, a worker can be assigned either a bicycle driver or a purchaser? Can we say that the efficiency (income minus cost) is X with a purchaser and X + Y with a purchaser and bicycle driver (i.e. the effect is linear)? If the effect is non-linear your problem will be much harder.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick-and-dirty test with a model that can handle teams. Just for illustration purposes.

I created two types of workers: type A and type B, and also teams consisting of two workers (one of each type). In addition, I created random cost data.

Here is a partial printout of all the data.

```
----     13 SET i  workers,teams

a1     ,    a2     ,    a3     ,    a4     ,    a5     ,    a6     ,    a7     ,    a8     ,    a9     ,    a10    
b1     ,    b2     ,    b3     ,    b4     ,    b5     ,    b6     ,    b7     ,    b8     ,    b9     ,    b10    
team1  ,    team2  ,    team3  ,    team4  ,    team5  ,    team6  ,    team7  ,    team8  ,    team9  ,    team10 
team11 ,    team12 ,    team13 ,    team14 ,    team15 ,    team16 ,    team17 ,    team18 ,    team19 ,    team20 
team21 ,    team22 ,    team23 ,    team24 ,    team25 ,    team26 ,    team27 ,    team28 ,    team29 ,    team30 
team31 ,    team32 ,    team33 ,    team34 ,    team35 ,    team36 ,    team37 ,    team38 ,    team39 ,    team40 
team41 ,    team42 ,    team43 ,    team44 ,    team45 ,    team46 ,    team47 ,    team48 ,    team49 ,    team50 
team51 ,    team52 ,    team53 ,    team54 ,    team55 ,    team56 ,    team57 ,    team58 ,    team59 ,    team60 
team61 ,    team62 ,    team63 ,    team64 ,    team65 ,    team66 ,    team67 ,    team68 ,    team69 ,    team70 
team71 ,    team72 ,    team73 ,    team74 ,    team75 ,    team76 ,    team77 ,    team78 ,    team79 ,    team80 
team81 ,    team82 ,    team83 ,    team84 ,    team85 ,    team86 ,    team87 ,    team88 ,    team89 ,    team90 
team91 ,    team92 ,    team93 ,    team94 ,    team95 ,    team96 ,    team97 ,    team98 ,    team99 ,    team100


----     13 SET w  workers

a1 ,    a2 ,    a3 ,    a4 ,    a5 ,    a6 ,    a7 ,    a8 ,    a9 ,    a10,    b1 ,    b2 ,    b3 ,    b4 ,    b5 
b6 ,    b7 ,    b8 ,    b9 ,    b10


----     13 SET a  a workers

a1 ,    a2 ,    a3 ,    a4 ,    a5 ,    a6 ,    a7 ,    a8 ,    a9 ,    a10


----     13 SET b  b workers

b1 ,    b2 ,    b3 ,    b4 ,    b5 ,    b6 ,    b7 ,    b8 ,    b9 ,    b10


----     13 SET t  teams

team1  ,    team2  ,    team3  ,    team4  ,    team5  ,    team6  ,    team7  ,    team8  ,    team9  ,    team10 
team11 ,    team12 ,    team13 ,    team14 ,    team15 ,    team16 ,    team17 ,    team18 ,    team19 ,    team20 
team21 ,    team22 ,    team23 ,    team24 ,    team25 ,    team26 ,    team27 ,    team28 ,    team29 ,    team30 
team31 ,    team32 ,    team33 ,    team34 ,    team35 ,    team36 ,    team37 ,    team38 ,    team39 ,    team40 
team41 ,    team42 ,    team43 ,    team44 ,    team45 ,    team46 ,    team47 ,    team48 ,    team49 ,    team50 
team51 ,    team52 ,    team53 ,    team54 ,    team55 ,    team56 ,    team57 ,    team58 ,    team59 ,    team60 
team61 ,    team62 ,    team63 ,    team64 ,    team65 ,    team66 ,    team67 ,    team68 ,    team69 ,    team70 
team71 ,    team72 ,    team73 ,    team74 ,    team75 ,    team76 ,    team77 ,    team78 ,    team79 ,    team80 
team81 ,    team82 ,    team83 ,    team84 ,    team85 ,    team86 ,    team87 ,    team88 ,    team89 ,    team90 
team91 ,    team92 ,    team93 ,    team94 ,    team95 ,    team96 ,    team97 ,    team98 ,    team99 ,    team100


----     13 SET j  jobs

job1 ,    job2 ,    job3 ,    job4 ,    job5 ,    job6 ,    job7 ,    job8 ,    job9 ,    job10,    job11,    job12
job13,    job14,    job15


----     23 SET team  composition of teams

team1  .a1 ,    team1  .b1 ,    team2  .a1 ,    team2  .b2 ,    team3  .a1 ,    team3  .b3 ,    team4  .a1 
team4  .b4 ,    team5  .a1 ,    team5  .b5 ,    team6  .a1 ,    team6  .b6 ,    team7  .a1 ,    team7  .b7 
team8  .a1 ,    team8  .b8 ,    team9  .a1 ,    team9  .b9 ,    team10 .a1 ,    team10 .b10,    team11 .a2 
team11 .b1 ,    team12 .a2 ,    team12 .b2 ,    team13 .a2 ,    team13 .b3 ,    team14 .a2 ,    team14 .b4 
team15 .a2 ,    team15 .b5 ,    team16 .a2 ,    team16 .b6 ,    team17 .a2 ,    team17 .b7 ,    team18 .a2 
team18 .b8 ,    team19 .a2 ,    team19 .b9 ,    team20 .a2 ,    team20 .b10,    team21 .a3 ,    team21 .b1 
team22 .a3 ,    team22 .b2 ,    team23 .a3 ,    team23 .b3 ,    team24 .a3 ,    team24 .b4 ,    team25 .a3 
team25 .b5 ,    team26 .a3 ,    team26 .b6 ,    team27 .a3 ,    team27 .b7 ,    team28 .a3 ,    team28 .b8 
team29 .a3 ,    team29 .b9 ,    team30 .a3 ,    team30 .b10,    team31 .a4 ,    team31 .b1 ,    team32 .a4 
team32 .b2 ,    team33 .a4 ,    team33 .b3 ,    team34 .a4 ,    team34 .b4 ,    team35 .a4 ,    team35 .b5 
team36 .a4 ,    team36 .b6 ,    team37 .a4 ,    team37 .b7 ,    team38 .a4 ,    team38 .b8 ,    team39 .a4 
team39 .b9 ,    team40 .a4 ,    team40 .b10,    team41 .a5 ,    team41 .b1 ,    team42 .a5 ,    team42 .b2 
team43 .a5 ,    team43 .b3 ,    team44 .a5 ,    team44 .b4 ,    team45 .a5 ,    team45 .b5 ,    team46 .a5 
team46 .b6 ,    team47 .a5 ,    team47 .b7 ,    team48 .a5 ,    team48 .b8 ,    team49 .a5 ,    team49 .b9 
team50 .a5 ,    team50 .b10,    team51 .a6 ,    team51 .b1 ,    team52 .a6 ,    team52 .b2 ,    team53 .a6 
team53 .b3 ,    team54 .a6 ,    team54 .b4 ,    team55 .a6 ,    team55 .b5 ,    team56 .a6 ,    team56 .b6 
team57 .a6 ,    team57 .b7 ,    team58 .a6 ,    team58 .b8 ,    team59 .a6 ,    team59 .b9 ,    team60 .a6 
team60 .b10,    team61 .a7 ,    team61 .b1 ,    team62 .a7 ,    team62 .b2 ,    team63 .a7 ,    team63 .b3 
team64 .a7 ,    team64 .b4 ,    team65 .a7 ,    team65 .b5 ,    team66 .a7 ,    team66 .b6 ,    team67 .a7 
team67 .b7 ,    team68 .a7 ,    team68 .b8 ,    team69 .a7 ,    team69 .b9 ,    team70 .a7 ,    team70 .b10
team71 .a8 ,    team71 .b1 ,    team72 .a8 ,    team72 .b2 ,    team73 .a8 ,    team73 .b3 ,    team74 .a8 
team74 .b4 ,    team75 .a8 ,    team75 .b5 ,    team76 .a8 ,    team76 .b6 ,    team77 .a8 ,    team77 .b7 
team78 .a8 ,    team78 .b8 ,    team79 .a8 ,    team79 .b9 ,    team80 .a8 ,    team80 .b10,    team81 .a9 
team81 .b1 ,    team82 .a9 ,    team82 .b2 ,    team83 .a9 ,    team83 .b3 ,    team84 .a9 ,    team84 .b4 
team85 .a9 ,    team85 .b5 ,    team86 .a9 ,    team86 .b6 ,    team87 .a9 ,    team87 .b7 ,    team88 .a9 
team88 .b8 ,    team89 .a9 ,    team89 .b9 ,    team90 .a9 ,    team90 .b10,    team91 .a10,    team91 .b1 
team92 .a10,    team92 .b2 ,    team93 .a10,    team93 .b3 ,    team94 .a10,    team94 .b4 ,    team95 .a10
team95 .b5 ,    team96 .a10,    team96 .b6 ,    team97 .a10,    team97 .b7 ,    team98 .a10,    team98 .b8 
team99 .a10,    team99 .b9 ,    team100.a10,    team100.b10


----     28 PARAMETER c  cost coefficients

               job1        job2        job3        job4        job5        job6        job7        job8        job9

a1           17.175      84.327      55.038      30.114      29.221      22.405      34.983      85.627       6.711
a2           63.972      15.952      25.008      66.893      43.536      35.970      35.144      13.149      15.010
a3           11.049      50.238      16.017      87.246      26.511      28.581      59.396      72.272      62.825
a4           18.210      64.573      56.075      76.996      29.781      66.111      75.582      62.745      28.386
a5            7.277      17.566      52.563      75.021      17.812       3.414      58.513      62.123      38.936
a6           78.340      30.003      12.548      74.887       6.923      20.202       0.507      26.961      49.985
a7           99.360      36.990      37.289      77.198      39.668      91.310      11.958      73.548       5.542
a8           22.575      39.612      27.601      15.237      93.632      42.266      13.466      38.606      37.463
a9           10.169      38.389      32.409      19.213      11.237      59.656      51.145       4.507      78.310
a10          50.659      15.925      65.689      52.388      12.440      98.672      22.812      67.565      77.678
b1           73.497       8.544      15.035      43.419      18.694      69.269      76.297      15.481      38.938
b2            8.712      54.040      12.686      73.400      11.323      48.835      79.560      49.205      53.356
b3            2.463      17.782       6.132       1.664      83.565      60.166       2.702      19.609      95.071
b4           39.334      80.546      54.099      39.072      55.782      93.276      34.877       0.829      94.884
b5           58.032      16.642      64.336      34.431      91.233      90.006       1.626      36.863      66.438
b6           49.662       4.493      77.370      53.297      74.677      72.005      63.160      11.492      97.116
b7           79.070      61.022       5.431      48.518       5.255      69.858      19.478      22.603      81.364
b8           81.953      86.041      21.269      45.679       3.836      32.300      43.988      31.533      13.477
b9            6.441      41.460      34.161      46.829      64.267      64.358      33.761      10.082      90.583
b10          40.419      11.167      75.113      80.340       2.366      48.088      27.859      90.161       1.759
team1        50.421      83.126      60.214       8.225      57.776      59.318      68.377      15.877      33.178
team2        57.624      71.983      68.373       1.985      83.980      71.005      15.551      61.071      66.155
team3         1.252       1.017      95.203      97.668      96.632      85.628      14.161       4.973      55.303
team4        34.968      11.734      58.598      44.553      41.232      91.451      21.378      22.417      54.233
team5        31.014       4.020      82.117      23.096      41.003      30.258      44.492      71.600      59.315
team6        68.639      67.463      33.213      75.994      17.678      68.248      67.299      83.121      51.517
team7         8.469      57.216       2.206      74.204      90.510      56.082      47.283      71.756      51.301
team8        96.552      95.789      89.923      32.755      45.710      59.618      87.862      17.067      63.360
team9        33.626      58.864      57.439      54.342      57.816      97.722      32.147      76.297      96.251
. . .
team98       21.277       8.252      28.341      97.284      47.146      22.196      56.537      89.966      15.708
team99       77.385      12.015      78.861      79.375      83.146      11.379       3.413      72.925      88.689
team100      11.050      20.276      21.448      27.928      15.073      76.671      91.574      94.498       7.094
(cost data for other jobs skipped)
```

My attempt to model this as **Mixed-Integer Programming model** is as follows:

[image]

Obviously, this is no longer a pure assignment problem. The first constraint is more complicated than we are used to. It says for each worker w, we can assign him/herself or any team that has w as member only once.

When I solve this without using teams, I get the following solution:

```
----     56 VARIABLE x.L  assignment

           job1        job2        job3        job4        job5        job6        job7        job8        job9

a5                                                                        1
a6                                                                                    1
b1                                    1
b3                                                1
b4                                                                                                1
b6                        1
b8                                                            1
b9            1
b10                                                                                                           1

  +       job10       job11       job12       job13       job14       job15

a1                                                                        1
a4                                                            1
a7                                    1
b2            1
b5                        1
b7                                                1


----     56 VARIABLE z.L                   =       59.379  total cost
```

This is a standard assignment problem, but I solved it as an LP (so I could use the same tools).

When I allow teams, I get:

```
----     65 VARIABLE x.L  assignment

               job1        job2        job3        job4        job5        job6        job7        job8        job9

a1                                                                                                                1
a5                                                                            1
a6                                                                                        1
b3                                                    1
b4                                                                                                    1
b9                1
b10                                                               1
team17                                    1
team28                        1

      +       job10       job11       job12       job13       job14       job15

a4                                                                1
a7                                        1
b2                1
b5                            1
team86                                                                        1
team91                                                1


----     65 VARIABLE z.L                   =       40.057  total cost
```

The objective is better (just because it could select teams with low "cost"). Also, note that in the solution no worker is selected twice (either individually or part of a team). Here is some additional solution report that confirms this:

```
----     70 SET sol  alternative solution report 

                  job1        job2        job3        job4        job5        job6        job7        job8        job9

team17.a2                                  YES
team17.b7                                  YES
team28.a3                      YES
team28.b8                      YES
-     .a1                                                                                                          YES
-     .a5                                                                      YES
-     .a6                                                                                  YES
-     .b3                                              YES
-     .b4                                                                                              YES
-     .b9          YES
-     .b10                                                         YES

         +       job10       job11       job12       job13       job14       job15

team86.a9                                                                      YES
team86.b6                                                                      YES
team91.a10                                             YES
team91.b1                                              YES
-     .a4                                                          YES
-     .a7                                  YES
-     .b2          YES
-     .b5                      YES
```

Note that the model is not very small:

```
MODEL STATISTICS

BLOCKS OF EQUATIONS           3     SINGLE EQUATIONS           36
BLOCKS OF VARIABLES           2     SINGLE VARIABLES        1,801
NON ZERO ELEMENTS         6,901     DISCRETE VARIABLES      1,800
```

However, the MIP model solves quite easily: less than a second.

I did not test the model on large data sets. It is just to show how one could approach a problem like this.

Comment: can you please add the libraries you use to solve the MIP model problem?

Comment: I used GAMS/Cplex. But this is a generic MIP model, so any MIP solver will do (at least for smaller instances). Large instances may require a bit more thinking.

Answer (score 0):

There's an obvious heuristic that you could try:

1. Solve the classical problem using the [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm),
2. Then using the pool of unassigned agents, find the combined assignment for each that gives the biggest improvement.

Certainly not the optimum, but a clear first-order improvement over the Hungarian Algorithm alone.

Comment: we have about 2 agents per job, so pool of unassigned agents could be large, so that the solution you suggest becomes computationally expensive. Thanks, still will try this approach on simulations

Comment: @ArtyomAkselrod It's really not that computationally expensive, it's only an extra `+O(n^2)` and the Hungarian algorithm is itself already `O(n^3)` or `O(n^4)` so it's not changing the big-O.